# Matrix 2.5.3 and Safecracker file 2.1 (EE 2.5.3) not playing nicely

Tags: matrix, safecracker

Ok, where to start. Firstly, I should say that there are similar topics to these, but I have my own unique set of problems, so I decided to post a new question.

Some background: This was an EE1 site which has been upgraded to EE 2.5.3 which i didn't do, and I'm now trying to fix the problems.
Of the many fields in the 'products' channel, one already created was a matrix field with one column, using safecracker file within it, for product images. This is the bit which isn't working correctly.

To start with, when loading a publish page with existing data (admin area) I get the following error appear at the top of the page;

```
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: safecracker_upload_dir
Filename: safecracker_file/ft.safecracker_file.php
Line Number: 567
```

The images within the matrix field seem to be appearing, so I'm not sure why this error message is appearing.
I've had a look at ft.safecracker_file.php and can see that the undefined index is that of the settings array - I assume it's pulling settings from the safecracker extension.
However, I have no idea how to set this, as there doesn't seem to be such an option in safecracker settings?

The problem part 2;

On the front end, when outputting the matrix tag pair - and then the matrix tag within it, I was initially having the problem of it not getting the image path.
If I prefix {filedir_6} (product images dir) manually to the image path in the matrix data table, I then get the path to appear.
Maybe someone could tell me whether this is a hangover from the EE1 upgrade?

Any and all help appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Hey Matt - do you have that problem with a standalone Safecracker File field?  Due to the error and version; I'd definitely recommend you upgrade to the latest EE (2.6) before continued troubleshooting.  For the second part of your problem - can you update your original post with both your template code, and the template output from that?  Thank you!